# Jquery show and hide div

Tags: jquery

I have 3 div as follows

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="spinnerDiv" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none"></div>
```

On a button click I want to show the div in the following way

> Step 1: Hide the div1
>   Step 2: Show spinnerdiv for few milliseconds say 3000
>   Step 3: Hide spinnerdiv and show div2

I have tried the follwoing method but its not working properly:

```
button click function(){
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#spinnerDiv").show().delay(3000).queue(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $("#div2").show();
    });
}
```

Comment: your code was working fine, check my answer with the snippet

Comment: You are right.Just got it wrong due to some errors from my side.Any way accepting answers that uses different approach other than the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with `setTimeout`:

```
$("#div1").hide();
$("#spinnerDiv").show();
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#spinnerDiv").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `setTimeout` instead?

```
button click function(){
     $("#div1").hide();
     $("#spinnerDiv").show();

     setTimeout(function () {
        $('#spinnerDiv').hide();
        $("#div2").show();
     }, 3000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a callback instead of hide() for the first part of the function, and since I am a not a fan of delay I would use a setTimeout:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").fadeOut(1, function () {
        var s = $("#spinnerDiv");
        s.show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            s.hide();
            $("#div2").show();
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you are

```js
function thisAction(){
     $("#div1").hide();
     $("#spinnerDiv").hide();
      $("#div2").hide();
     
     $("#spinnerDiv").show().delay(3000).queue(function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $("#div2").show();
            });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="div1">div 1</div>
 <div id="spinnerDiv" style="display:none"> spinnerDiv</div>
 <div id="div2" style="display:none">div2</div>

<button onclick='thisAction()' >
```

Comment: Here please click the button once again after the animation effect.